# facebook page widget shows different app id when user not logged in facebook and try to like page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have `Facebook page widget`, and i want to track if user liked my page or not. If not then force them to like. I did code for that, but now issue is when user try to like page and not logged in, `Facebook` open login window and app id is different on that window(which is default, don't know from where it takes).

[image]

And because of that, users not able to authorize my app. And i cant track details of that users.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this means they can't like the page - it's not clear what you're asking

Comment: @Igy let me clear what i want, i want user to like my page when he came to my site. so i added like widget in popup. issue is when user click on like button there are 2 case 1)either user already logged in 2) not loggeed in. os if not logged in and click on like button i want to login user using my app but it not happening it shows login box with different app id. but if i click on share then it shows my app id.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why that breaks the plugin, though - that's probably the app ID used by the plugin when no app ID was used to intialise it

Comment: @Igy i already have code for initialization with my app id.if so then why share button shows correct app id if i am not logged into facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using [`Page Plugin`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin), instead of the now-deprecated [like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/). It's hard to say without seeing any code, but it sounds like you are either using the SDK/plugin incorrectly, or using something like a 3rd party wordpress plugin that may be acting maliciously by injecting another ID.